# Cycles not rendering Principled Volume emission smoothly

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, smoke-simulation, emission

I am trying to render emissive lights in my smoke using Principled Volume node in Cycles render, but emission light is not rendering correctly.

[image: Emission]

When I set emission to 0 Cycles renders volume material as expected

[image: Emission 0]

What am I doing wrong here? Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably have to use the density as an input for the emission strength to achieve that. If you need the volume to have a higher emssion value then just pop a math node in between the density and the emission strength and multiply it.

Here's my setup:

before:
[image: before]

and after:
[image: and after]

Answer (score 1):

To ensure that emission only comes from within the smoke, make sure that the 0 position on the color ramp is black. This way, any part of the object that has a density of 0 will also emit nothing.

The blocky shape that you are seeing is an optimized domain that will not occupy as much screen area when rendering compared to the entire bounding box. This will improve render times significantly since volumetric rendering in Cycles is very slow.

Answer (score 0):

Yay works like a charm, this is my new setup.
[image]